# Select word under cursor using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard

What is the keyboard shortcut to select a word that your typing cursor is currently on ?

For example, if the word I want to select is `World`, while the typing cursor is between one of the letters of that word such as `This Wo|rld is huge`, what do I press to select only `World` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know a single shortcut to select the word, but you can do it in two steps, by first moving the cursor to the start of the word, then select the word.

1) Move cursor to left of word:

⌥←

2) Select word to right of cursor:

⇧⌥→

Of course you could do a similar thing with moving to the right of the word with ⌥→ then selecting the word to the left of the cursor with ⇧⌥← if you prefer.

Comment: That is a good substitute.

Comment: omg! why xcode don't have built-in hotkey for such useful action?

Answer (score 12):

You could also create ~/Library/KeyBindings/ and save this as DefaultKeyBinding.dict:

```
{
    "~w" = selectWord:; // option-w
}
```

You have to reopen applications to apply changes. DefaultKeyBinding.dict doesn't work in Xcode or some cross-platform applications, but you could use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) as a fallback:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>Xcode</name>
<identifier>private.xcode</identifier>
<only>XCODE</only>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::W, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

Comment: Ahh I actually wanted this feature to be used in Xcode. THanks though.

Comment: I'm using the updated version of KeyRemap4MacBook (aka "Karabiner") and couldn't get the XML config to work (OPT-W insists on inserting a greek :sigma: rather than running the macro). However, the `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` worked fine (OSX Mavericks).

Comment: is there a system wide option for this?

Comment: I don't have this directory. Should I create it first? Where is it documented? What other shortcuts are possible?

Answer (score 8):

In the current version of Xcode, you can set up the shortcut in Preferences... ( ⌘, ) -> Key Bindings, filter "select word", then you can choose a new shorcut by typing it in the field "Key" associated

Comment: Why was this voted down? It works for me with Xcode 9.3.1

Comment: That works! (Xcode uses almost all conceivable key bindings by default, so the challenge is to find one that is available, or pick one to swap:-)

Comment: Works with Catalina and Xcode 11

Answer (score 3):

1. Open **Preferences..**
2. Go to **Key Bindings** > **Text** tab
3. Thus it does not provide default shortcut. You have to customize it by setting keys.
   [image]

Comment: which app are these preferences for? I can't find this in system preferences and OP never specified an app

Comment: For XCode @BlkPengu